# Uploading an image to parse database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform

So this is what I have tried so far:

I have built a bit of code that takes a photo (only the important snippet):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    _camera_button.hidden = true;
    _camera_imageview.hidden = false;
    [_next_camera setEnabled:YES];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
    [self upload_selfie:imageData];
    
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And then when you click on a button I want it to upload to the database. This is what I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)upload_selfie:(NSData *)data{
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.png" data:data];
    [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Hide old HUD, show completed HUD (see example for code)
            
            // Create a PFObject around a PFFile and associate it with the current user
            PFObject *selfie = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"selfie1"];
            [selfie setObject:imageFile forKey:@"imageFile"];
            
            
            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
            [selfie setObject:user forKey:@"imageFile"];
            
            [selfie saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

Where `selfie1` is made on parse like this:
[image]

---

But I am getting an error: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Any ideas why?

---

The break point notified me of this:

[image]

And these:
[image]

And I have noticed this:

[image]

And this from the debugging:

[image]

---

## How i connect `upload_selfie` to the <kbd>button</kbd>

[image]

---

## Photo of undeclared identifier error:

[image]

Comment: Show the full exception message and stack trace

Comment: Do you mean like this: `2014-04-17 18:51:49.704 Retort[539:60b] -[UIButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1455118d0
2014-04-17 18:51:49.708 Retort[539:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1455118d0'` ?

Comment: `*** First throw call stack:
(0x182fde950 0x18f4e41fc 0x182fe3604 0x182fe1330 0x182f0108c 0x1000bfe08 0x1000bfd00 0x10008c500 0x185fdd0c8 0x185fdd05c 0x185fc6538 0x185fdca5c 0x185f99e0c 0x182f9f0a8 0x182f9c330 0x182f9c6bc 0x182edd6d0 0x188bc1c0c 0x18600efdc 0x10008f900 0x18fad7aa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) `

Comment: something to do with this: `0x100137e08:  cmp    x0, #10485760` ?

Comment: Is it because usually an `IBAction` waits for a unique parameter which is `sender` (in our case an `UIButton`)? That's the reason I see why it would but the `UIButton` on the "data" parameter instead of your argument. It's just speculation, but that could be a thing to check.

Comment: @Larme that didn't work unfortunately!

Comment: What did you try exactly? If you could do so, you may want to set an property on the NSData you want to pass between the two methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a few try. It may need a few works/tests, but:
Here could be a solution:

Change:

```
- (IBAction)upload_selfie:(NSData *)data
```

To:

```
- (IBAction)upload_selfie:(id)sender withData:(NSData *)data
{
    if ([data isKindOfClass:[NSData class]])
    {
    //Put the rest of your code, it what would called manually
    }
    else
    {
        // User clicked on the button, but didn't "send" data with it.
    }
}
```

Call it with `[self upload_selfie:nil withData:imageData];`

The question: Why?
If you call an `IBAction` method, you'll send with it the `sender`.
Remember, we usually write: `-(IBAction)actionMethod:(id)sender`. If you want to check the sender, you may do, in case of a UIButton: `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;`
So, from what I understood, this kind of method will take the first parameter as the sender if it's called from an user interaction (by opposition of a call by code with `[self actionMethod:mySender]`.

But a thing I don't understand is why you put it as a `IBAction` at first, and seem to link no "direct user action" to it.

Edit:

After more explanation, I'd suggest this:
Add:
`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *imageDataToSend;`

Replace `[self upload_selfie:imageData];` with: `[self setImageDataToSend:imageData];`

Replace `PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.png" data:data];` with: `PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.png" data:imageDataToSend];`

Replace `-(IBAction)upload_selfie:(NSData *)data` with `-(IBAction)upload_selfie:(id)sender` or `-(IBAction)upload_selfie:(UIButton*)button` since your seems quite confused.

What you may add: put `self.imageDataToSend` to `nil` once it's send. Check at the beginning of the  the `IBAction` method if `imageDataToSend` is not `nil`. I don't know how all of your code works, but once you clicked on `upload_selfie` you may also want to disable the button, in case of the user click many times (and you send unnecessary many times the sames image), and "reable" once the sending is done (with `[button:setEnabled:TRUE/FALSE];`).

Comment: The "direct user action" is from a touch up inside button -> `upload_selfie:` ?

Comment: I have tried changing everything and I now get the error: `-[ViewController upload_selfie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136d141e0
2014-04-19 10:36:00.046 ****[1292:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController upload_selfie:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x136d141e0'`

Comment: You'll have to change the connection on the IB part.

Comment: You have to clear things: What really call `update_selfie`? Is it the button connected in InterfaceBuilder? Or is it called by code? If it's the button, I don't know how you pass it the photo `data`.

Comment: it is the button I thought it was passing the data through: `[self upload_selfie:imageData];` ?

Comment: You issue seems to be about misunderstanding. I edited my answer. You seem quite confused about what you're doing.

Comment: I am very confused I am sorry! I tried the method you have mentioned in your edit the first time round but I receive an error `use of undeclared identifier'imageData'` see photo in question.

Comment: My bad, your error line: `imageData`=> `imageDataToSend`, I edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but I put it as an answer to highlight another error.

Your error message states that an object of type UIButton is sent the message "length", which it doesn't have. I can't see anything in your code that could cause this, so I believe the error comes from elsewhere. Please add the whole stack trace, and maybe I can update the answer with a solution to the other error as well.

But your code has another error, and that is here:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[selfie setObject:user forKey:@"imageFile"];
```

You already set imageFile as the image. This should probably be

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
[selfie setObject:user forKey:@"user"];
```

or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched and searched but I cant for the life of me find out where the "length" comes from ?? any clues on where it might be?

Comment: Although it shouldn't matter; does it make any difference if you try [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; instead?

Comment: Where sorry? I am confused.

Comment: At the top of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Comment: Still no luck!?? Do you need any more info? This is doing my nut in!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3f);    
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]] data:data];
    TLPhoto *photo = [TLPhoto new];
    [photo setImageFile:imageFile];
    [photo setAlbum:album];
    [self setPermissionsForObject:photo];

    // Save the image to Parse
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [photo save];
        [album.photos addObject:photo];
        [album saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        }];
    })
```